# How to set filter to process not all requests?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt, spring-rest

I'm using Spring Core, Spring MVC, Spring REST, JWT.

Hello everyone!

I'm learning Spring Security and I encountered a problem.

I would like to make an authentication based on JWT; I have a Rest controller with 3 simple methods:

The first method should be available for everyone, the second only for signed in users, and the third only for admins. And although that is working, I have another problem.

The problem is that my filter throws(not directly, because the null is returned by `token = header.substring(7)`) a `NullPointerException` each time after starting, even when it doesn't get any request yet(I can be wrong, I hope that code will clarify it). Is it possible to set a filter to process only chosen requests or maybe my approach is wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sample.config.JwtFilter.getAuthenticationByToken(JwtFilter.java:50)
    at com.sample.config.JwtFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtFilter.java:36)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My `JwtFilter`:

```
public class JwtFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public JwtFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);

    }

    @Override   
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header=request.getHeader("authorization");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authResult=getAuthenticationByToken(header);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthenticationByToken(String header) {
            String token = header.substring(7);
            Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("fQx]n}YmL)WuHjL".getBytes()).parseClaimsJws(token);

            String username=claims.getBody().get("name").toString();
            String role = claims.getBody().get("role").toString();
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,null,Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role)));      
    }

}
```

My configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new AuthenticationManager() {

            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/test2").authenticated()      .antMatchers("/api/test3").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .addFilter(new JwtFilter(authenticationManager())); }
}

public class SpringSecurityWebInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{

}
```

The controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TestApi {

    @GetMapping("/test1")
    public String test1()
    {
        return "test1";//for everyone
    }

    @GetMapping("/test2")
    public String test2()
    {
        return "test2";//only for logged in
    }

    @GetMapping("/test3")
    public String test3()
    {
        return "test3";//only for admins 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have your application configured, your filter will be invoked for every request because the security `FilterChain` "applies" to every request.

This line:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/test2").authenticated()      
        .antMatchers("/api/test3").hasRole("ADMIN")
        ...
```

... does not prevent a request from going through the `FilterChain`. It simply allows a request matching those paths to pass through the filters without being authenticated. But every filter you register (like `JwtFilter`) will be invoked.

## Solution

You could disable the entire `FilterChain` for certain requests by overriding the `configure(WebSecurity)` method in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().mvcMatchers(...);
}
```

But in your case, it's better to change your filter so that it skips certain requests based on the path of the request coming in. You could do something like:

```
public class JwtFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    private AntPathRequestMatcher filterPath;

    // the path you provide will restrict the filter to only be "applied"
    // to requests with that path
    public JwtFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, String path) {
        super(authenticationManager);
        this.filterPath = new AntPathRequestMatcher(path);
    }

    @Override   
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        // the filter will do nothing if the request doesn't match
        if(!filterPath.matches(request) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

        // your filter logic goes here...

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Based on your advice, I made a little correction:
 
  if (header == null) {
   chain.doFilter(request, response);
   }
And now it is working!